# Alternative primers for Sikkens Cetol Filter 7?

Tags: staining, water-protection, oiling

I need to coat some exterior timber and have a tin of Sikkens Cetol Filter 7 lying around.  There are many references online to using Cetol HLS as a primer.

Does anyone know if a primer is essential under Cetol Filter 7, and if so whether oil based stains in general would be suitable (products other than HLS)?

Comment: Welcome to WSE.   This site encourages users to do a little research before placing a question.  Sikkens site states the following on the product webpage: "Use: As a topcoat over Cetol HLSe on most types of timber" & " Filter 7 plus should not be applied directly to bare timber." For application over other products such as stain, I suggest you inquire with the manufacturer.

Comment: Thanks!  It probably wasn't very clear, but I have read the same online myself.  I have already contacted Sikkens (understandably, they can only advise on their own products), so weren't they able to help in this instance - hence my reaching out to an active community of woodworkers to see if any of you guys/gals had any practical experience with this product.

Comment: It may or may not be relevant to suggestions, but in case it is can you explain exactly what you want to do, *"I need to coat some exterior timber"* doesn't actually tell us anything specific. Telling us what species and the application wouldn't hurt either.

Comment: Now re. how you use these products generally (going by the manufacturer's marketing blurb) Cetol HLS is used as a "base stain" under higher-build finishes such as Cetol Filter 7 plus or Cetol THB plus *on smooth planed exterior joinery*. The Cetol Filter 7s blurb states it is the *recommended* finish coat of a two-part system with Sikkens HLS as the 'primer'. That does seem to indicate that it's not essential, but this is reading between the lines and I'm not sure it could be taken to be a direct implication. It is worth noting however that most such finishes don't require any sort of primer.